# Containers and shared ownership within a class instance

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I have two objects as member variables of a class.

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> specificObject;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> objects;
```

I know that `specificObject` will always be within `objects`. How can I point to `specificObject` without using `shared_ptr`s as I do not want the ownership of the objects in the container to be considered shared? Is this a case where a raw pointer can be used, or is `shared_ptr` really the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ideal world, all owning pointers are smart pointers, and raw non-owning pointers are only used when NULL is considered a potentially valid value. If it is indeed true that `specificObject` will *always* be within `objects`, then at least in theory it should be possible to make `specificObject` be an `Object` reference, thereby allowing the compiler to enforce that it always has a non-NULL value for its entire lifetime.

In a less than ideal world, it might not be feasible or even possible to initialize `specificObject` to point to a member of `objects`, depending on how exactly `specificObject` is determined and whether that logic can reasonably be `constexpr`'d. Then the question comes down to whatever the lifetimes of all the `Object`s within `objects` are. If you know that they will all continue to exist at least as long as `specificObjects` does, then a non-owning raw pointer is perfectly safe. I suspect this is the most typical situation.

In a very non-ideal world, it may be possible for `objects` to gain and lose any of its members at any time, so you need to account for the possibility that `specificObject` gets invalidated while your program is still trying to do stuff with it. In this case, `weak_ptr` is the tool of choice, as it's specifically designed for situations where you don't know when the object's lifetime might end, yet you don't want to needlessly prolong it. Of course, that would require changing all your `unique_ptr`s to `shared_ptr`s, and unsurprisingly it is the least intuitive of the smart pointers, which is why I'm mentioning this option last.

Comment: Alas... `objects` will likely change constantly and the specific object being pointed to may vanish entirely. Am I doomed to have to use `shared_ptrs `forever??? It seems that anytime I start to use polymorphism and containers in C++ (which is always) I am forced to use `shared_ptrs`.

Comment: @sydan If your objects have very unpredictable lifetimes and need to be used in multiple places, then yes, I can't imagine getting anything done without `shared_ptr`s or some equivalent thereof.